# Calculation of traceless second fundamental form

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

The traceless part of second fundamental form is 
$$
\mathring A = A -\frac{H}{n}g
$$
where $A$ is second fundamental form, $H$ is mean curvature, $g$ is metric. The norm square is 
$$
|\mathring A|^2 = |A|^2-\frac{1}{n}H^2.
$$
I want to verify it. What I do:
\begin{align}
|\mathring A|^2  &=g^{ij}g^{kl}\mathring A_{ik}\mathring A_{jl}  \\
&=g^{ij}g^{kl}(A_{ik} -\frac{H}{n}g_{ik})(A_{jl} -\frac{H}{n}g_{jl})  \\
&=g^{ij}g^{kl} (A_{ik}A_{jl}-\frac{H}{n}g_{ik}A_{jl}
-\frac{H}{n}g_{jl}A_{ik}
+(\frac{H}{n})^2g_{ik}g_{jl})  \\
&=|A|^2 -\frac{2H}{n}g^{ij}A_{ij} + (\frac{H}{n})^2\delta_k^j\delta_j^k
\end{align}
Then, I don't know how to deal it. I can't think though why $\delta_k^j\delta_j^k =n$ and what is $g^{ij}A_{ij}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$H$ is by definition the trace of $A$ with respect to $g$, i.e. $g^{ij} A_{ij}.$ The contraction $\delta^j_k \delta^k_j$ is equal to $n$ because it reduces to $\delta^j_j,$ which is just the trace of the $n \times n$ identity matrix.

Comment: I thought the mean curvature was $\frac{1}{n}tr_gA$?

Comment: @STUDENT: this is just a choice of convention, both definitions are in use.